# Vertically align text inside a div with percentage height and width?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I know how to align text vertically inside a div, but I am unsure on how to do it if the div has a percentage height and width. Here is my code:

```
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    #header {
        background-color: red;  
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%; 
        height: 15%;
    }
```

Now on my webpage the text in the div has been aligned correctly horizontally but not vertically. How do I fix this problem? Can you also try to explain your answers and keep them as simple as possible please (I'm still relatively new at HTML/CSS). Thank you.

Comment: You maybe change the right answer to that one using `flexbox`. The current answer does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving `display:inline-block` to your h1 tag.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4be9cp23/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! What does that line mean though?

Comment: It means the margins of the h1 won't collapse with the margins of the #header div and body. That's all. It has nothing to do with vertical alignment. To see, try setting the height of `#header` to say, 200px.

Comment: This is not working at all - I modified the punker http://jsfiddle.net/4be9cp23/269/

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`flexbox` model](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to easily center things.

Just add the following rules to your container:

```
display:flex;
justify-content: center; //horizontal centering
align-items:center; //vertical centering
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hccp3cj2/)

**Note** this is probably a more general solution than what you expected, but what's really cool about `flexbox` is that it works in many different cases, including yours (example with an `h1` tag [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hccp3cj2/1/)).

Comment: Nice solution! Keep in mind that this working on old browsers http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add `line-height` matching the `height` of the container:

```
#header {
    background-color: red;  
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 15%;
    line-height: 0.15em;
}
```

Comment: Line-height as a percentage is a percentage of the font-size, not a percentage of the container height.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add:

```
display:inline-block
```

to your h1

example: http://jsfiddle.net/24pwprvf/

Answer (score 0):

You should not use line-height for the effect you desire as suggested by Praveen Above.

You can get the same affect by either putting, 'display: inline-block' in either the #header div or in the #header h1 css style.

the first part is not advisable.Best practice will be to use it in the h1 style only.